# Let V be a vector space over F. Is $\mathcal L(V)$ a ring extension of F?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $F$-vector space. Then consider the set of linear maps from $V$ to itself, $\mathcal L(V)$. We know that $\mathcal L(V)$ is a vector space over $F$. Is this also a ring extension of $F$?

Comment: If $V = \{ 0 \}$ then $\mathcal{L}(V) \simeq \{ 0 \}$ becomes the zero ring so it doesn't contain $F$ (or any field).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Makes sense! Edited to account for this

Answer (score 0):

This is true if $V$ is not the zero vector space.

We need to show that $\mathcal L(V)$ is a ring, and that it contains a field isomorphic to $F$.

$\mathcal L(V)$ is an $F$-vector space where addition and scalar multiplication are defined as follows: For $S, T \in \mathcal L(V)$, $\lambda \in F$,

- $(S+T)(v) = Sv+Tv$
- $(\lambda T) v = \lambda (Tv)$

Now define multiplication in $\mathcal L(V)$ as composition $ST(v) = S(T(v))$. Under the original addition and this multiplication, $\mathcal L(V)$ can be viewed as a ring: Let $v \in V$, and $S, T, U \in \mathcal L(V)$.

1. $(\mathcal L(V), +)$ is an abelian group: Follows since $\mathcal L(V)$ is a vector space
2. Multiplication closure: Let $R=ST$. Then $R(v)=S(T(v))$. Since $T(v) \in V$, $S(T(v)) \in V$.
3. Multiplication associativity: $(ST)U(v) = S(T(U(v))) = S(TU)(v)$.
4. Multiplicative identity: Let $I \in \mathcal L(V)$ be the identity operator on $V$, where $I(v)=v$. For any $T \in \mathcal L(V)$, $(TI)(v) = T(I(v)) = T(v)$ and $(IT)(v) = I(T(v)) = T(v)$
5. Distributivity: $S(T+U)(v) = S(T(v)) + S(U(v)) = (ST + SU)(v)$, and $(T+U)S (v) = T(S(v)) + U(S(v)) = (TS + US)(v)$

Under these operations, $\mathcal L(V)$ contains a field isomorphic to $F$: $\mathcal L(V)$ contains $\text{span }I = \{\lambda I \mid \lambda \in F\}$ where $I$ is the identity operator just defined. This is a field, because

- $\text{span }I$ is a subring of $\mathcal L(V)$:

  - $(\text{span }I, +) \leq (\mathcal L(V), +)$: Follows since $\text{span }I$ is a subspace of $V$
  - $\text{span }I$ is stable under multiplication: Let $\lambda_1 I, \lambda_2 I \in \text{span }I$. Then $(\lambda_1 I)(\lambda_2 I)(v) = (\lambda_1 I (\lambda_2 I(v)))=\lambda_1 \lambda_2 I(v)$ by linearity of $I$
  - $\text{span }I$ contains the multiplicative identity: Clear
- $\text{span }I$ has multiplicative inverses: For any $\lambda I \in \text{span }I$, consider $\lambda^{-1} I$ where $\lambda^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $\lambda$ in $F$, which exists since $F$ is a field. Then $(\lambda I(\lambda^{-1} I(v))) = \lambda \lambda^{-1} I(v) = I(v) = v$ by linearity of $I$

$\text{span }I$ is isomorphic to $F$: Consider the map $f: \text{span }I \rightarrow F$, $\lambda I \mapsto \lambda$. This is a field isomorphism, because

- $f((\lambda_1 I) + (\lambda_2 I)) = f(\lambda_1 I) + f(\lambda_2 I)$: $f((\lambda_1 I) + (\lambda_2 I)) = f((\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)I) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2= f(\lambda_1 I) + f(\lambda_2 I)$ by distributivity
- $f((\lambda_1 I) (\lambda_2 I)) = f(\lambda_1 I) f(\lambda_2 I)$: $f((\lambda_1 I) (\lambda_2 I)) = f(\lambda_1 \lambda_2 I) = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 = f(\lambda_1 I) f(\lambda_2 I)$ by linearity of $I$
- $f(I) = 1$: True since $I = 1I$ by $\text{span }I$ being an $F$-vector space
- Injective: True since all nontrivial field homomorphisms are injective
- Surjective: Let $\lambda \in F$. Then $f(\lambda I) = \lambda$.

We have just shown that $\mathcal L(V)$ as a ring contains a field $\text{span }I$ isomorphic to $F$. Actually, if $V$ is finite-dimensional, $\mathcal L(V)$ is also isomorphic to the matrix ring.